# how progressive web app differ from normal web application in terms of performance

Tags: javascript, web, web-applications, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have been reading about progressive web app for now, pwa uses service worker for offline caching to speed up performance. But why i cant we use localstorage for the same purpose as service worker? so that if we didnt get response from api request we can load the data from local storage. And normal browser cache for the assets?

may be this is dumb question but still thought of asking the question. any advices appreciated.

Comment: So are you asking about performance, or functional differences…?

Comment: It's very broad, not the right place to ask. Here is to help people debug their code.

Comment: @deceze, im more interested about functional differences. cant we store the data in local storage and load it

Comment: @Jeremy SO isn't *exclusively* about debugging code, you know.

Comment: @deceze could you please elaborate? This kind of question is always flagged as "too broad".

Comment: @Jeremy What about questions along the lines of *"I have A, I want to get to C, what to do about B?"* Those can be reasonable questions and they're not about debugging code. A question may still be *too broad* for other reasons, e.g. if "B" would require a whole book to answer.

Comment: That's right, fair enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first of all, a service worker runs on a different thread then the main application. that's why you could use a service worker for improved performance since, it's operations won't affect your main application.

You can use the localstorage for storing data on the client side, but you can't use it for offline caching. To get data from the localstorgage you need to have a script loaded first, that will try to access the localstorage.

SeriveWorkers are also stored in the client, and they can intercept the network layer. So within your service worker you can decide if you want to load a specific route from the cache first or try to request it from the network.

checkout this video that explains concept pretty well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBfLvqA_E4A

Comment: the js/html files can be cached with browser cache itself right ? so in that case what is the advantage of service worker

Comment: when go offline and try to load a website, your browser attempts to load the resources from the network and will fail. if you have a service-worker in place that intercepts those resource requests, it can redirect it to point to the cache. have a look at https://pwa.rocks/ for example

Comment: Regards to the caching of api requests, how do i cache an api request which is not yet called , that is it is in another page of the app ?

Comment: you can't cache data you don't have. but you can intercept an api request (identified by the request url) and respond with anything you want. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Custom_responses_to_requests) you get more information on that

Comment: thanks Shabby, i have one more doubt. I have added my pwa to home screen through instal banner. After that i am deleting the icon from home screen. then again the install banner is not showing. is there any way to show that ?

Answer (score 0):

you absolutely can use localStorage to mimic the caching features offered in service workers. I started doing this about 6-7 years ago.
https://love2dev.com/blog/use-local-storage-to-make-your-single-page-web-application-rock/
However, I would advise against localStorage as your caching provider. Instead use IndexedDB. Back then IDB was not supported by Safari and IE. Today all current browsers support IDB.
If a browser does not support service worker, ie Safari, you can fall back to this caching strategy. The big difference is all the caching happens on the UI thread, and not a background thread. It will work offline - you need to add an appCache manifest to your site. FYI when service workers are supported and you have an appCache manifest the service worker wins. Your appCache is not honored. This is by design and a good example of progressive enhancement.

I will post more on this technique soon and include it in my PWA course.

Comment: Thanks for the info